# How to enable back my Play/Pause, Forward, Rewind functionality on my Magic Keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, media-player

I've accidentally disabled those functionalities because I found it annoying that the Music app was always popping up when trying to pause a youtube video so I ran this command:

`launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist`

It disabled those three buttons completely and now I'm having trouble getting them back.

What I've tried:

- Changing the setup in  > System Preferences > Keyboard.
- Removing my keyboard and reset to default settings.

Is there a way to redo the command above ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to simply load back the launchctl.

`launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.rcd.plist`

Comment: was looking for this for months. thanks a ton!